# apt-get gives error: Unable to locate package <package name> for all packages

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-server, apt-get

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 13.10, and I'm trying to install an FTP server, but apt-get doesn't seem to want to install anything.

`sudo apt-get install vsftpd` brings the error: `unable to locate package vsftpd`.

So I tried it again, but with installing the program "cowsay" instead. The same thing happens.

I did try `apt-get update`.

I tried `sudo apt-cache search vsftpd`, and nothing returned. however, if I type the same command on my normal Ubuntu machine (not the server), then results do pop up.

So what's wrong?

Comment: Did you install all repos? As sudo, edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list and uncomment all lines beginning with deb. Save, run apt-get update

Comment: that didn't work. after running apt-get update, this error popped up: `Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`, and after running apt-get install vsftpd again it says `duplicate sources.list entry` everywhere, but running that with cowsay acts like it did previously.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` somewhere ?

Comment: I pasted it [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IQSveht3ZZ9GXCuXqP3TLsLq-PY45fkO166Oa6DEfFk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sources.list file has two duplicate software sources in it, and there may be other things wrong with it as well.

A standard sources.list file for Ubuntu 16.04 looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

A standard sources.list file for Ubuntu 18.04 looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

A standard sources.list file for Ubuntu 20.04 looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

After you do that, tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about by running the following command in the terminal:

A standard sources.list file for Ubuntu 22.04 looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

After you do that, tell your system to refresh the software database from each archive it knows about by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
```

It is possible to regenerate the default sources.list file manually by following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586595/restore-default-apt-repositories-in-sources-list-from-command-line/586601#586601).

Comment: that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I updated the answer, I forgot to tell you to run `sudo apt-get update` after you finish editing the sources.list file.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it still not working. is it possible to reinstall apt-get? maybe its just corrupt or something.

Comment: Before you do that I've got another idea. You can regenerate your whole sources.list file from scratch and rename your old sources.list file as a backup. Visit the repogen [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/). Don't forget to run `sudo apt-get update` to update your list of software after you replace your sources.list file.

Comment: Quick note for future users that repogen dosen't seem to have updated since 2018 and won't work on 'newer' releases